# I can attach to docker swarm as worker but can not attach as manager

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

After sudo docker swarm join --token XXXXX YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:2377 I can attach to swarm as worker successfully. Than I leave this swarm from secondary/slave node and try again with management token. And receive:

**Error response from daemon: manager stopped: can't initialize raft node: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = could not connect to prospective new cluster member using its advertised address: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded**

Both nodes directly connected one to another. Firewall in both node is not working. What can be a reason of this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a node as worker and promote it to manager role

```sh
docker swarm join --token XXXXX YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:2377
```

And on the manager node:

```sh
docker node promote SECOND_MANAGER_HOSTNAME
```

Answer (score 1):

For me port 2377 was not open as a TCP destination in the subnet ingress rule.
I am using VMs from different VPCs.